# ocaml syntax error in let expression following module definition

Tags: syntax, ocaml

I have the following ocaml code:

```
module type blah = sig
...
end

module blah1 = struct
...
end

module blah2 = struct
...
end

let arr = [|("blah1", 2); ("blah2", 1)|] in
  arr
```

The ocamlopt reports a syntax error on line "let arr". Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete example that shows the problem:

```
# module M = struct end let x = 14 in x;;
Error: Syntax error
```

The problem is that your `let` is parsed as the second in a series of top-level definitions. Hence the `in` is syntactically incorrect.

The top level of a module has the following syntax:

> module-items ::= {;;} (definition ∣ expr) { {;;} ( definition ∣  ;; expr) } {;;}

This says you can have a definition or expression. Then you can have another definition or expression. If the second item is an expression, you have to have `;;` between the first and second items.

Since your `let` expression has no purpose (it doesn't define a value and has no side effects) it's difficult to say how to fix your code.
One possibility is to add the `;;` as just described. Another possibility is to make your your `let` into a definition: `let () = ...`:

```
# module M = struct end let () = ignore 14;;
module M : sig end
```

Since I like to avoid `;;` in my source code, I usually have only definitions (no top-level expressions) in my modules.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more about “let is parsed as the second”? You mean it is a part of the previous module definition? I think the let expression is fine by itself, that is if I get rid of those module definitions, it is complied fine. So what’s the interaction between let and module definitions?

Comment: I expanded my answer. I got the syntax from Chapter 7, Section 11 of the OCaml manual.

Comment: I see. Do you know the purpose of this design. I can understand that if there are two consecutive let expressions, you need to put a ;; at the end of the first expression, otherwise, the second expression will be in the scope of the first expression. But here the case is different.

Comment: I imagine it avoids shift/reduce conflicts in exactly the case you show. Your code looks exactly like a definition until you reach `in`. (But I don't really know, this is a guess.)